# Java sort list with streams first by length then alphabetically

Tags: java, sorting, java-stream, compare, comparator

I can sort already by the description length, but how can I alphabetically sort two `Article` if two of them have the same length? (if the description of two articles has the same length, then the sorting should be alphabetical).

```
   public List<Article> sortAsc() {
    removeNull();
    return articles.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a.getDescription().length()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}




public class ComparatorAppController implements Comparator<String> {

/***
 * compare each element
 * @param o1
 * @param o2
 * @return
 */
public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
    // check length in one direction
    if (o1.length() > o2.length()) {
        return 1;
    }
    // check length in the other direction
    else if (o1.length() < o2.length()) {
        return -1;
    }
    // if same alphabetical order
    return o1.compareTo(o2);
}
```

}

How can I use my Comparator for this situation? Or should I change it to something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to sort first by description length and then by description (alphabetical order), then your first comparison is fine but you also need to add a second comparison by description.

You can stack a second comparison by using the method `thenComparing()`. It will perform the second comparison only for elements with same length. There is no need to implement a custom `Comparator` for this scenario.

```
public List<Article> sortAsc() {
    removeNull();
    return articles.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt((Article a) -> a.getDescription().length())
                .thenComparing(Article::getDescription))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your custom comparator seems good. However in the `sorted` method of `streams` you use another comparator.

This is how you can pluggin your custom comparator considering it is in the same class with the following block of code.

```
  return articles.stream()
            .sorted(this::compare)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Comparator.comparing(KeyExtractor,Comparator)`

```
public List<Article> sortAsc() {
    removeNull();
    return articles.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.getDescription(), new ComparatorAppController()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Or define all the criterias with some `thenComparing*`

```
public static List<Article> sortAsc() {
    return articles.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.<Article>comparingInt(a -> a.getDescription().length())
                    .thenComparing(Article::getDescription))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you need to sort in `stream` ,you can simply call 'sort' method for your list.

```
articles.sort(new ComparatorAppController());
```

You can add n numbers of comparator in `sort` method.
eg:-

```
articles.sort(new ComparatorAppController().thenComparing(new SomeOtherComparing()));
```

You can also use `thenComparing` in the `stream` also.

```
articles.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a.getDescription().length()).thenComparing(new SomeOtherComparing()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete your comparator and build one using `comparing()` and `thenComparing()`:

```
articles.stream()
  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(a -> a.getDescription().length())
                    .thenComparing(Article::getDescription))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```